# VST audio samples

Tags: decompilation

Ques: How difficult would it be to extract audio samples from a VST extension/plugin?

The author has made their software available for [free](http://blog.wavosaur.com/rave-generator-vst-free-90s-stab-synth/) but it was designed as an extension for a much larger music framework? VST?

My synth can load and play raw WAV files. How hard would it be to extract the audio samples from the author's plugin, and would it be possible to convert the samples into individual WAV files?